# Why should we return object in Python overloading

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning Python overloading operation. I'm overloading the `__add__` operation in class. why should i have to return in the form of object at the end to overloading function. The code is given below

```py
class point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y

    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y +other.y
        return point(x,y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1})".format(self.x,self.y)

point1 = point(1,2)
point2 = point(1,2)
print(point1+point2)
```

Another code for the same

```py
class point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y

    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y +other.y
        return (x,y)



point1 = point(1,2)
point2 = point(1,2)
print(point1+point2)
```

Both the above code gives the same result. I don't understand why 'return point(x,y)' is used in first example

Comment: Do you want `point1+point2` to be a `tuple` or a `point`? Either one is valid. The question is what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: Your code is not good. Please explain what you want to achieve?
If you are saving the `x` and `y` in class's instance variable than you don't need to return it. It will always available in all the methods or through the object

Comment: If I add two objects of type `point` together, I would (99% of the time) expect to receive another `point` object as the output.

Answer (score 3):

These are not the same, one returns an instance of the `point` class, another returns a `tuple`. What is printed is the same, due to how `__str__` is defined for the `point` class.

You don't *need* to return another instance of the `point` class, but I can imagine there are use cases where this would be desired. Also, it's quite natural to assume that the group of instances of the `point` class is "closed" under addition, meaning that adding two instances of the class results in another instance of the class.

See what happens in such a case, when I want to get a point that results from adding two points. In case of returning `return point(x,y)`, I can just assign the result of addition to some variable, e.g., `point3 = point1 + point2`. In case of `return (x,y)` I'd have to do something convoluted like `point3 = point(*(point1 + point2))` or `point3 = ((point1 + point2)[0], (point1 + point2)[1])`.